# What are the best templates to give oozes a better to-hit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, monster-design

Pretty self-explanatory. Try to keep it under CR 5 tough. It is for [bottled ooze](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/bottled-ooze-su/)s, as per the alchemist discovery.

Comment: Are you the GM? If not, I would make sure they accept that Bottled Ooze *allows* you to choose templates, as well any any template you would choose to add. Also, based on your other question's use of Gelatinous Cube, are you sure you want to-hit and not a bonus to it's Reflex DC? Engulf requires no attack roll.

Comment: i asked the question. He is still thinking about it. Yeah bonus to the reflex DC could be useful but i won't use only gelatinous cube. I'd like to summon combat oozes too, and the cube might fail it's engulf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the GM actually allows you to add templates to your oozes (which you should make sure of first), the [Advanced Simple Template](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/advanced-creature-cr-1/) might be what you're looking for. It's my go-to solution for upgrading monsters slightly on the fly:

> **Quick Rules:** +2 on all rolls (including damage rolls) and special
> ability DCs; +4 to AC and CMD; +2 hp/HD.
>
> **Rebuild Rules: AC** increase natural armor by +2; **Ability Scores** +4 to
> all ability scores (except Int scores of 2 or less)

Benefits:

- Can be added to any creature (including oozes)
- Only increases CR by 1 (which should help keeping the CR low/below 5)
- Overall better stats, including attack rolls ("*to-hit*") and the reflex DC, in case you're using a [Gelatinous Cube](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/gelatinous-cube/)
- No need for tons of recalculations, which allows applying the template on the fly, in case you want to experiment with many different types of oozes